# How to perform Integration test using Gradle for separate projects?

Tags: java, testing, jenkins, gradle, integration-testing

I have a Java Gradle Project named "code" which conatains Java code which is to be tested. And I have a separate gradle project named "itest" which contains code for the integration testing. And I am building these code using Jenkins.

code -- /src/main/java

Now, in which project I should write task for integration testing in build.gradle file and how should i provide link to the correct project whose java code is to be tested. Can I test code from some other project?

Comment: Yes, you can test code from a different project. Just add your code project as a dependency in your test project - Ensure that you build the code project first and always ensure that you're testing against the correct version. Buy why are they organized as separate projects in the first place?

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to know and learn, so asked. Later on when I have given some more thought, I merged the code project and test project.